# Не корректно создается массив int

Tags: python, list

leadsClear:

```
[{'id': 1472181, 'main_contact': 123456, 'count': 3}, 
{'id': 2036907, 'main_contact': 465789, 'count': 3}, 
{'id': 2039071, 'main_contact': 123789, 'count': 3}, 
{'id': 2036873, 'main_contact': 78946, 'count': 3}]
```

Создаю массив Int таким образом:

```
numbers = []
for i, elem in enumerate(leadsClear):
    numbers.append(leadsClear[i]['main_contact'])
```

В `'main_contact'` расположен int.

И если отправлять в JSON. То сервер не принимает `numbers`

Если создавать так `numbers = [321654, 3216987]`, то сервер воспринимает `numbers` корректно.

Сам запрос:

```
urlCreateDialOuts = 'https://callapi.gravitel.ru/api/v1/createdialout'
headersCallApi = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
jsonCreateCallApi = {'connectaction': '2', 
                 'linecnt': '1', 
                 'numbers': numbers, 
                 'redirecturi': '100@test.gravitel.ru', 
                 'timefrom': '12:00', 
                 'timeto': '16:00', 
                 'token': 'token', 
                 'type': '1'
                 'userdata': '12345, 3'}
createDialOuts = requests.post(urlCreateDialOuts, headers=headersCallApi, json=jsonCreateCallApi).json()
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно создать массив int?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос структуру `leadsClear`. Если там есть чувствительные данные, то измените их. Кст, ваш код можно упростить: `numbers = [x['main_contact'] for x in leadsClear]`

Comment: Там список словарей `[{'id': 1472181, 'main_contact': 123456, 'count': 3},
    {'id': 2036907, 'main_contact': 465789, 'count': 3},
    {'id': 2039071, 'main_contact': 123789, 'count': 3},
    {'id': 2036873, 'main_contact': 78946, 'count': 3}]` И если вывести `numbers`, то выводит корректно

Comment: Тогда непонятно, что может пойти не так. Покажите в вопросе код отправки JSON

Comment: А зачем enumerate() использовать??

Comment: `{
    "connectaction": "2",
    "linecnt": "1",
    "numbers": numbers,
    "redirecturi": "100@test.gravitel.ru",
    "timefrom": "12:00",
    "timeto": "16:00",
    "token": "token",
    "type": "1",
    "userdata": "12345, 3"
}`

Comment: А если отправить так `"numbers": [123456, 456123]`, то все норм.

Comment: @danilfg, два замечания, добавьте в сам вопрос (я об этом специально писал), используйте кнопку **править**, второе, просил сам код, а не просто `json` :) у меня пока нет идей почему у вас не работает, т.к. `numbers = [321654, 3216987]` и тот, что в цикле будет сделан будет иметь одинаковую структуру -- список чисел и не будет разницы в json. Еще, советую использовать обращение по нику @+<ник>, когда несколько участников в комментариях, чтобы тому, кому пишите пришло уведомление, иначе ни кому не придет

Comment: @gil9red, добавил. Спасибо.

Comment: numbers у вас нормально генерится, хотя и неэффективно, проблема в чём-то другом

Comment: @CrazyElf, как можно понять в чем проблема?

Comment: @Nobody, не знал как по другому, теперь знаю)

Comment: @danilfg, как выше писали, дело не в способе получения `numbers`, но я могу предложить пример того как можно посмотреть какие данные отправляется тем запросом `requests`: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/3ca2490500c0836c14c782cde54f3c9a034b4820/requests__examples/debug_logging__requests.py#L10 Добавьте в код те строки и при запуске увидите данные и заголовки. Останется понять чем отличаются ваши варианты

Comment: @danilfg Мне кажется, у вас всё же словарь, а не json, а вы передаёте его как будто json в функцию requests.post. Может надо сначала сделать преобразование словаря в json (примеры можно легко нагуглить).

Comment: Какую конкретно ошибку возвращает сервер? Он должен вернуть json с сообщением, что конкретно ему не нравится (как в примере "неуспешного ответа" в [документации](https://www.gravitel.ru/upload/gravitel_call_api.pdf))

Comment: @gil9red, запустил с этим кодом, проверил ответ построчно и при передачи переменной и при передаче [123456, 456123]. В первом случае `reply: 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n'`, во втором `reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'`

Comment: @CrazyElf, если просто отправить запрос без переменной, а с параметрами в самом запросе, то все норм.

Comment: @insolor, `17 Внутренняя ошибка сервиса`

Comment: @danilfg А вы уверены, что сам сервис нормально воспринимает массив произвольной длины?

Comment: @danilfg Поставьте Fiddler, если ещё не стоит он у вас и смотрите, какой запрос в итоге уходит на сервер, возможно, это вас на что-то натолкнёт, на какую-то мысль

Comment: @CrazyElf, спасибо! Действительно отбивает из-за длины номеров. Буду общаться с разработчиками.